# Vertically centered line in text with custom length

Tags: latex

I am trying to create a vertically centered line inside normal text. I also want to control length and width of the line as the dash or "---" are to thin and/or short.

I want something like the math-command \rule{length}{width}, which is centered like a dash and not floored.

[Example (not created with Latex)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4aMP.png)

Comment: Please make a [mre] and also add a sketch how the result should look like

Comment: Are any of the other [Unicode characters for hyphens/dashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hyphens_and_dashes) useful to you?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz If I had a MWE the question were obsolete.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Like I stated in the question the dash or "---" are not useful for me. In fact also "--" or the minus sign are not useful.

I edited the question so it hopefully becomes more clear.

Comment: @Jaans At the very minimum you could create a simple test document, including a class and some dummy text. Such things are always so boring to type.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I don't mean to be rude, I just don't really know what you're asking of me. I honestly don't care which class or dummy text I use. I have created an example image of what I want. I don't expect anyone to write my code for me, I am just looking for command suggestions or someone who was encountered the same issue and came up with a workaround.

Comment: google `latex horizontal centered bar` shows various answers at tex.stackexchange, such as [horizontal line in middle (text-alignment)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236754/horizontal-line-in-the-middle-text-alignment). Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, `\rule` can be raised just by specifying how high you want it.

```
\rule[0.5ex]{1in}{0.4pt}
```

raises a `\rule{1in}{0.4pt}` 0.5ex above the baseline.